# How can I prevent rain from dripping off the roof rake edge?

Tags: roof, shingles

Recently I have noticed that about 1-2’ from where the roof would drain into the gutter, water is dripping over the edge of the house on the side. What would cause that to happen? Nowhere else around the house does it do this.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What actual problem are you trying to solve? Your house will get wet when it rains, and that's not a problem statement.

Answer (score 3):

That is not unusual if you live in an area where the wind /rain are blowing at an angle to the home. Even with no real wind it can happen and a photo would be helpful. It may be a slight difference in the stagger of the shingles or possibly the overhang has a slight sway or droop there we usually leave a bit of an overhang on the sides and I probably would not worry , but a photo might reveal an issue that we can point to.

Comment: How do I add a picture?

Comment: I added photos to the original post.

Comment: I just noticed the update. I believe what you have is normal, there is no way to stop the driven rain or gravity flow. You might try adding a bead of silicon sealer but this could hold water and cause problems. I would say this is normal from what I see. The roof pitch is somewhat flat so any creases in the tarpaper could redirect some flow.

Answer (score 1):

Wind / slight pitch variation at that portion of the roof maybe...

You can add a "rain diverter:. Basically, something to redirect the water towards the gutter at the edge of the roof.

You can lift the shingles a bit and slide a L shaped piece there for example, say 2" x 2". You may not even have to attach it.

I've even seen home owners use a piece of drip edge upside down.